# Meta-analysis Hazard Ratio

Tags: meta-analysis, hazard

I need to explain the calculations involved in a meta-analysis with Hazard ratios (random effects) for programming in a tool. It is not possible to use statistical softtware neither webpages where these calculations are implemented. 
We will have available the HRs and their 95%CI, where we can deduce the SE of the ln(HR) coefficients. The sample sizes will be not available.
Do you know some website where these calculations are well explained, with some example?

Answer (score 3):

From the Cochrane Handbook:

"if estimates of log hazard ratios and standard errors have been obtained from results of Cox proportional hazards regression models, study results can be combined using the generic inverse-variance method (see Section 9.4.3.2). Both fixed-effect and random-effects analyses are available [here](http://handbook.cochrane.org/chapter_9/9_4_9_meta_analysis_of_time_to_event_outcomes.htm).

Formulas are available [here](http://www.cochrane.org/sites/default/files/uploads/handbook/Statistical_Methods_in_RevMan5-1.pdf).

Hope this helps.

Abou-Setta